# Integrating Firebase with flutter - Not working

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have problems in firebase. I intergrated flutter app with firebase. I got initialization succesfful.
if i run a code to load image from firestorage. The image doesnt appear.
I tried to follow all post regarding the errors in log. but nothing works out.

Log errors:

> 2021-02-03 10:27:26.279 14915-15001/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token
> retrieval failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED 2021-02-03 10:29:26.371
> 14915-15001/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed:
> AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
>
> 2021-02-03 11:39:53.497 23775-23775/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to
> start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Not allowed to start service Intent {
> act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT
> pkg=com.google.android.apps.messaging
> cmp=com.google.android.apps.messaging/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService
> (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{a1881c4 u0a85 SVC
> idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

Dependencies

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core' implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth' implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: image doesnt loading

Comment: Where are you initializing Firebase?

Comment: added google-service.json..app/build gradle. registered app with firebase.

Comment: When app starts, you are initialized Firebase? In a main class or something else.

Comment: now i added initialization in main.dart. but still the page is loading. why? no image loaded

Comment: E/StorageUtil( 5686): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.

Comment: You need to sign in to the system. You can follow [this](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/super-simple-authentication-flow-with-flutter-firebase-737bba04924c) tutorial for auth setup.

Comment: thank u. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSkJs.png)    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

```
class Dash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashState createState() => _DashState();
}

class _DashState extends State<Dash> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _getImage(context, 'images/image_1.jfif;'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                  ConnectionState.done)
                return Container(
                  height:
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.25,
                  width:
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.25,
                  child: snapshot.data,
                );

              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                  ConnectionState.waiting)
                return Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                        2.25,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                        2.25,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator());

              return Container();
            },
          ),
          Text('hjjjh'),
        ],

      ),

    );

  }

}
Future<Widget> _getImage(BuildContext context, String imageName) async {
  Image image;
  await FireStorageService.loadImage(context, imageName).then((value) {
    image = Image.network(
      value.toString(),
      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    );
  });
  return image;
}

class FireStorageService extends ChangeNotifier {
  FireStorageService();
  static Future<dynamic> loadImage(BuildContext context, String image) async {
    return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(image).getDownloadURL();
  }
}
```